# Выборка из sql таблицы по нескольким столбцам

Tags: sql

Имеется таблица SQL с листом WORDS со столбцами:

```
#, Add Date, Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4.
```

Необходимо выбрать те строки, которые содержат текущую дату в столбцах пяти дат.
Пробовал выбирать вот так:

```
SELECT * 
FROM WORDS 
WHERE `Add Dɑte`='31.12.2018' 
   OR `Date1`='31.12.2018'
```

Проблема в том, что при этом запросе выбираются только те строки, которые удовлетворяют последнему условию. Но эта дата есть и в столбце `Add Dɑte` и во всех других столбцах, но на разных строках.
А я в результате получаю только те строки, которые в столбце `Date1` содержат эту дату.
Как выбрать все строки с этой датой, содержащейся либо в столбце `Add Dɑte` либо в любом из следующих?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE CURRENT_DATE IN (`Add Date`, Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4)
```

где CURRENT_DATE - любая доступная в используемом диалекте (и контексте) функция, возвращающая текущую дату. Как вариант - вставляемый вручную или передаваемый как параметр литерал даты.